# Port LAMP application to EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lamp

Any good resource on how to port a LAMP stack to Ec2?

Mainly I'm concerned about storage, the MySQL part. The existing app works agains a single store. Do I need to port all my storage to S3? Will the EC2 instances be able to share a single MySQL database? Alternatively I can partition my data and have a single database for each EC2 image, but I still need a global user account database for authentication and if the data is partitioned the requests have to be routed to the proper image. Not sure how this is achieved in EC2.

To wrap up: where should I start?

Answer (score 3):

These [Tips for deploying a LAMP stack on Amazon EC2](http://www.livingdigitally.net/2009/04/tips-for-deploying-a-lamp-stack-on-amazon-ec2.html) are IMO a really good starting point. I'd suggest to read them first (I'm not sure I understand your concerns about the storage part), maybe things will be clearer after.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone who's in this situation check out: http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/04/how-to-create-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-apache-php-and-mysql-lamp/

That is the most straight forward tutorial I've found for implementing a LAMP stack on Amazon EC2.

Using S3 isn't required, although it *is* an affordable way to host files. Yes, multiple instances can share a single database and you can use database replication for additional availability. Here's a great tutorial for that: http://aciddrop.com/2008/01/10/step-by-step-how-to-setup-mysql-database-replication/